# Is setting the render target back to backbuffer supposed to take long?

Tags: xna, 2d, monogame, rendertargets

I am creating a game in Monogame (XNA extension). I draw to a render target to display menu items for my game. Everything works fine, however... Whenever I set the render target back to the back buffer of my graphics device

```
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

it takes a long time (more than a second). This would be fine if I just needed my menu items at the beginning of the game. However if the game resets due to player input I have to re-initialize some of the menu items using the render target this lengthy process gets annoying.

Before I try to debug this, has anyone else experienced time delay with setting the render target back to the graphics back buffer? It works just fine when I set the render target to a created render target.

```
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget( new RenderTarget2D( device, width, height) );
```

That works just fine.

Edit:

I tried debugging this (C# is not my greatest language), and reached the line GL.BindFramebuffer( GLFramebuffer, this.glFramebuffer); inside ApplyRenderTargets inside GraphicDevice.cs of the Monogame Framework (Not my code).

The delay is occuring when you are trying to bind a framebuffer to a specified frame buffer target inside the OpenTK library. Debugging further requires I get OpenTK. I have to go out right now, but when I get back I'm going to test this on an XNA project (I have tested this in another monogame project with the same results) and attempt to debug further.

Edit 2:

The problem Setting the Render target back to the device back buffer after drawing to a large render target ( 8000 X 8000 ) causes the delay. I don't know the reason why I thought the buffers just swapped out.

Edit 3:

I am going to have to look into how setting render targets actually works. For now the time delay is fine, since I will have loading screens / asynchronous loading as the player progresses in the game to deal with these delays. In the end the the render target swapping the render target from a very large one causes a small delay, this seems to be expected behaviour.

Edit 4: Looking into a better solution than using a large render target.

Edit 5: Check answer

Comment: `SetRenderTarget(null);` shouldn't be producing this type of issue. Have you tried any sort of profiling?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Check my edit, got any idea why its happening?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with MonoGame or OpenTK to know. Try to see if some good 'ol fashion Google might be able to pull something. I'll try to get a test project on my test bed later if you haven't got it by then.

Comment: Haha its ok, when I get back I'm going to download the latest OpenTK version and try to debug this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that if you must debug a specific library, you're most likely doing something wrong in your own code.

Comment: Your right, I just tested this with XNA it works just fine. I tested this on two different game projects in mono game and seemed to freeze. So I assumed it was happening in Monogame, however it was a terrible assumption. I tried it again in a new monogame project and it didn't freeze this time. Gonna look into this more and post whats happening when I get home.

Comment: Ok figured out the problem, gonna try and come up with a solution. See Edit

Comment: 8000x8000x4bpp = ~256MB just for the colour buffer. You can double that if there's a depth buffer. It might be you're running out of video memory and it's having to transfer lots of data back and forth to main memory every frame.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. I have to look into how setting render targets works, as I thought when you were switching render targets it was as simple as changing the indexing in the frame buffer. 

Thankfully this time delay is not a big deal since in my game I will have loading screens / asynchronous loading after user progression.

Thanks for the help guys, see final edit

Comment: @BenCheng: Adam means that you can't fit both buffers in memory at the same time.  Trying to switch may require copying the big buffer back to main memory and then copying the main buffer back out of main memory into the GPU.  I can't think of a good reason to need an 8000x8000 buffer - state what effect you're trying to achieve, we might have a better solution.

Comment: If you've reached a conclusion, please post that as an answer rather than as an edit to the question.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Ah I see what you mean now, it would require a lot of memory to keep that buffer in video memory. I want to represent a world-map within a mini-map. The world-map is static, so I decided to use a render target. However the world map is large (8000 x 8000). Using this render target it is easy to represent player position on the map by just using a specific source section of the texture rectangle, and drawing it at the top / bottom of the screen. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch I could divide the texture up, and calculate which area of the map the user is in. If these areas intersect I could use cropping to draw multiple textures into the mini-map space. Just seems a little unnecessary to avoid a small time delay upon level loading. Can you think of another solution? Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @BenCheng: that's an entirely different question than the performance one and you should post a new question if you want solutions on that, rather than trying to discuss it in comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Adam and Sean for helping find the most likely cause of the slow load being large frame buffers and the regular buffer can't both sit in video memory, so when the buffers switch the large buffer probably has to be copied into main memory and the device back buffer copied from main memory back to video memory.